# Export AWS resources via CloudFormation script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I have several resources deployed in my AWS organization across several zones, such as:

- Several S3 buckets
- EC2 instances
- CloudFront distributions
- ACM certificates

I would need to store the resources and their content/configuration in a CloudFormation script, so that they can be redeployed in the future if needed.
Online I find controversial information and it's not clear to me how to export existing resources as CloudFormation script, if even possible when the resources are stateful.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to put this is "Import resources to a CloudFormation Template" you can read about this [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html)

To check which resources are supported by the import operation, read about it [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-supported-resources.html)

Of course you can go ahead and create a CloudFormation Template from scratch that deploys the existing resources in your account but it does not import those exact resources and test it in a separate account or same account. Make sure you do not break existing application configuration by doing so.

Comment: In that page I can see how to create those resources but not how to recreate the exact same resources (including content and configuration). For example: I have an S3 bucket called test, inside I have 20 folders and files. I want to export the config of the bucket along with its content via Cloudformation. But this shouldn't be done manually.

Comment: Afaik there is no tool that does this automatically, I suggest you use aws cli to describe the resources you want to add to your CloudFormation Template and add them, then you need to test your template by deploying it. You can deploy to the same account by changing the resource name and network config where that is needed(e.g., ENIs)

Comment: So I can basically import only stateless resources.

Comment: No wrong, you can import resources displayed [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-supported-resources.html](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-supported-resources.html) , I never claimed they have to be stateless.

Comment: Ok then how do I import an S3 bucket including content and configuration?